# WEB_HOOK channel unavailable when trying to retrieve Google calendar events

Tags: heroku, push-notification, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use [Push notifications for Google Calendar](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/push)

Callback endpoint is hosted on Heroku. **appname.herokuapp.com** is verified in Search Console and added to Google Console APIs & Services Allowed domains list.

**Request**

```
POST /calendar/v3/calendars/CALENDAR_ID/events/watch HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "id":"1",
    "type": "web_hook",
    "address":"https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/change"
}
```

**Response**

```
400 Bad Request
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "push",
                "reason": "channelUnknown",
                "message": "WEB_HOOK channel unavailable for: 
{address=https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/change}"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "WEB_HOOK channel unavailable for: {address=https://APPNAME.herokuapp.com/change}"
    }
}
```

What

> WEB_HOOK channel unavailable

error means?

EDIT: same result with a top level domain which certificate's Subject matches exactly the domain name.

Comment: Also started happening today at my environment at around midnight UTC.
Code unchanged, same certificate valid until 2020.

Existing channels still work: Google sends the payloads to the same URL it claims "unavailable".

Comment: happening for me too.

Comment: The same, why it happens?

Comment: is there a workaround?

Comment: started yesterday at 12PM PST for our systems

Comment: is there a way we can ask google? since as I understand all our applications are literally down.

Comment: Suspect that we all have port forwarding for this web hooks...

Comment: Have the same. Not doing anything with port forwarding @dvelopp. Notifications for existing channels are pouring in just like before.

Comment: Here is a link to the issue in the Google Calendar issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170

Comment: Anything on this? Started roughly 8 hours ago.

Comment: Google has acknowledged the issue and say that they are currently working on addressing it.  -- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170#comment20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was a temporary issue and [is now fixed according to Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170#comment26). (I also tested and seems to be working for me, now.)