# Getting error "WEB_HOOK channel unavailable" while watching Google calendar push notifications

Tags: push-notification, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

Currently I started getting:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "push",
    "message" : "WEB_HOOK channel unavailable for: {address=https://...}",
    "reason" : "channelUnknown"
  } ],
  "message" : "WEB_HOOK channel unavailable for: {address=https://...}"
}
```

When I try to start watching Google Push Notifications. 
I have my domain verified and the url is available for Post Requests in the Internet. Notifications are just not coming to it. What might be wrong here?

Comment: There is another example here you may want to follow that incase they get an anwser https://stackoverflow.com/q/50918537/1841839.   IMO looks like somethings down on googles side.

Comment: Also seeing this exact behavior.  Started yesterday roughly 12PM PST.

Comment: Did you manage to find the reason why or workaround?

Comment: I suspect maybe it's because of port forwarding?

Comment: Guys, shared a link to this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WEB\_HOOK channel unavailable when trying to retrieve Google calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918537/web-hook-channel-unavailable-when-trying-to-retrieve-google-calendar-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue on Google's end. They are working on addressing it

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170#comment20

Credit: [@dvelopp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929508/getting-error-web-hook-channel-unavailable-while-watching-google-calendar-push/50950245#comment88870782_50929508)

Update: There was an issue with the Calendar API that was resolved

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110373170#comment26